# How do I modify the "build script" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, release

My release build will not compile. Exactly where in the Android Studio project do I make the suggested change?
Error: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
Modify your build script as follows:

android {
    lintOptions {checkReleaseBuilds false}}

Comment: app/build.gradle

Comment: That works... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `app/build.gradle` file.

For more information please take a look at the [Configure Your Build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/) page of the Android documentation.